# How to nullify vars in order to execute inner_join function?

Tags: r, dplyr, inner-join, tidyverse

I was using inner_join function to combine two objects. Code look something like this

```
combined <- inner_join(weekly,nifty.curr.weekly) %>% as.data.frame()
```

I got the following error

```
combined <- inner_join(weekly,nifty.curr.weekly) %>% as.data.frame()
Joining, by = "date"
Error in inner_join_impl(x, y, by$x, by$y, suffix$x, suffix$y, check_na_matches(na_matches)) : 
  unknown group column 'year'
```

I tried this

```
weekly$year <- NULL
```

But it didn't worked.

`str(weekly)` gives me something like this

```
'data.frame':   1249557 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ date         : Date, format: "2008-10-10" "2008-10-17" ...
 $ co_code      : int  11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 ...
 $ company_name : chr  "20 MICRONS LTD." "20 MICRONS LTD." "20 MICRONS LTD." "20 MICRONS LTD." ...
 $ weeklyreturns: num  -0.3718 -0.0509 -0.3021 0.0568 0.1823 ...
 - attr(*, "vars")= chr  "co_code" "company_name" "year"
 - attr(*, "drop")= logi TRUE
```

Clearly there is "year" but `head(weekly)` shows me no column as year. I am fairly new to R. Help me out.

`dput(head(weekly))` output is

```
structure(list(date = structure(c(14162, 14169, 14176, 14183, 
14190, 14197), class = "Date"), co_code = c(11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L), company_name = c("20 MICRONS LTD.", "20 MICRONS LTD.", 
"20 MICRONS LTD.", "20 MICRONS LTD.", "20 MICRONS LTD.", "20 MICRONS LTD."
), weeklyreturns = c(-0.371829432619424, -0.0508551219831974, 
-0.302077648370433, 0.0567530464383245, 0.182326044668884, -0.123195412632735
)), vars = c("co_code", "company_name", "year"), drop = TRUE, .Names = c("date", 
"co_code", "company_name", "weeklyreturns"), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

`dput(head(nifty.curr.weekly))` output is

```
structure(list(date = structure(c(10963, 10970, 10977, 10984, 
10991, 10998), class = "Date"), niftyreturns = c(1.31650630176203, 
0.584047024147951, -0.132578988695284, -1.33554800612288, 0.0406396054173438, 
9.31911281754924), currencyreturns = c(NA, 0.0345117017291674, 
0.137835997012159, 0.0917622932404161, 0, 0.011490168178474)), .Names = c("date", 
"niftyreturns", "currencyreturns"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Hi can you share the output of `dput(head(weekly))` and `dput(head(nifty.curr.weekly))`?

Comment: dput output included in question.

Comment: In datasets you provided there is no mutual date

Comment: No mutual date??

Comment: In the question you've provided dput for nifty.curr.return but in your code you join nifty.curr.weekly. When I take your dputs, and give the five rows a mutual date on which to join, the join is successful for me.

Comment: As @Berenger has already wrote, your examples are joining successfully. Maybe you should try to specify a `by` argument? For your full datasets, of course. Smth like `inner_join(weekly,nifty.curr.weekly, by = "date")`

Comment: Ok. Thanks . I will try that